# Schema compliance in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to do schema compliance of an input file in ADF. I have tried the below.

1. Get Metadata Activity
2. The schema validation that is available in source activity

But the above seems to only check if a particular field is present or not in the specified position. Also Azure by default takes the datatype of all these fields as string since the input is flat file.

I want to check the position and datatype as well. for eg:-

**empid,name,salary**
1,abc,10
2,def,20
3,ghi,50
xyz,jkl,10

The row with empid as xyz needs to be rejected as it is not of number data type. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data flow and create a filter to achieve this.

Below is my test:

1.create a source
[image]

2.create a filter and use this expression:`regexMatch(empid,'(\\d+)')`
[image]

3.Output:
[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: @SreeVik Can you mark this as answer ?Thanks a lot.